# Matching table of events to the most recent parent event in Redshift

Tags: sql, join, amazon-redshift

I have two tables in my Redshift database: "consultations" and "orders." The "consultations" table has columns `consultation_id`, `patient_id`, and `consultation_date`. The "orders" table has columns `patient_id`, `order_date`, and `line_items`.

I need to write a SQL query that matches each order to the most recent consultation ID of the corresponding patient. If an order occurs before a given consultation, it should be matched to the most recent consultation before that order.

For example, given the two tables:

`orders`:

| patient_id | order_id | order_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | OA1 | 2023-01-02 |
| A | OA2 | 2023-01-03 |
| A | OA3 | 2023-01-05 |
| B | OB1 | 2023-01-06 |
| B | OB2 | 2023-01-08 |

`consultations`:

| patient_id | consultation_id | consultation_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | CA1 | 2023-01-01 |
| A | CA2 | 2023-01-04 |
| B | CB1 | 2023-01-01 |
| B | CB2 | 2023-01-07 |

I want to get the following table output:

| patient_id | order_id | consultation_id | order_datetime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | OA1 | CA1 | 2023-01-02 |
| A | OA2 | CA1 | 2023-01-03 |
| A | OA3 | CA2 | 2023-01-05 |
| B | OB1 | CB1 | 2023-01-06 |
| B | OB2 | CB2 | 2023-01-08 |

This is what I've attempted so far:

```
SELECT
    o.patient_id,
    o.order_date,
    o.line_items,
    c.consultation_id,
    c.consultation_date
FROM
    orders o
JOIN (
    SELECT
        c1.patient_id,
        c1.consultation_id,
        c1.consultation_date
    FROM
        consultations c1
    WHERE
        c1.consultation_date = (
            SELECT
                MAX(c2.consultation_date)
            FROM
                consultations c2
            WHERE
                c2.patient_id = c1.patient_id
                AND c2.consultation_date <= o.order_date
        )
) c ON o.patient_id = c.patient_id
ORDER BY
    o.patient_id, o.order_date;
```

However, this query throws an error: "relation o does not exist," and I suspect it's due to the second AND condition in the join subtable.

How can I modify this query to achieve the desired result of matching each order with only the most recent consultation, considering the conditions mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use a left lateral join , try the modified code below
SELECT
    o.patient_id,
    o.order_id,
    o.order_datetime,
    c.consultation_id,
    c.consultation_date
FROM
    orders o
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
        c1.consultation_id,
        c1.consultation_date
    FROM
        consultations c1
    WHERE
        c1.patient_id = o.patient_id
        AND c1.consultation_date <= o.order_datetime
    ORDER BY
        c1.consultation_date DESC
    LIMIT 1
) c ON true
ORDER BY
    o.patient_id, o.order_datetime;
```

Comment: Lateral joins don't exist in Redshift (see docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Join_examples.html) ) unlike in Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches to this depending on your circumstances. Unfortunately I’m traveling and don’t have my computer so this will be more descriptive.

Option 1: If your data isn’t too large and there aren’t a lot of earlier consultation dates for each patient this will be easier and likely faster. Join the tables on patient id and an inequality comparison on consultation date being less than or equal to order date time. This will match all the earlier consultation dates so you need to find the latest in an outer select. since you want the consultation id as well as the consultation date you will want to do this with a row_num window functions and then select the most recent consultation date row for each patient and order date.

The downside of this approach is that it will loop join with all earlier consultation dates and possibly make a huge data segment. If this is larger than memory the query will spill and slow down greatly.

Option 2: Union the tables together and since they have different columns you will need to have the superset of columns and add a new date column that coalescence of consultation date and order date. This new date applies the ordering between the 2 types of row so you will want to make sure that an order for a date always comes after the consult for the same date.

Now you have a data segment that can’t be larger than the sum of the rows in both tables. In the extreme this will be much smaller then the data segment in option 1.

To extract the result you will need to window over this data, partitioned by patient and ordered by the new date column with rows unbounded preceding, to find the max consultation date. This can be put inside a case statement to only run the window if order date is not Null.

This associates the most recent consultation date with each order date for each patient. Now it is a simple 1 to 1 join on patient id and latest consultation date to add the consultation id.

The downside with this is that it is complex and possibly slower when the loop join in option 1 easily fits in memory. The upside is that it won’t explode when the data tables grow.

Sorry for no code snippets but this is a limitation of my situation. I’ll try to respond to questions as travel permits.